# Hear two beeps after wake

Tags: mac, audio, sleep-wake

When I sleep my MacBook Pro and then lift the lid to wake it, after several seconds I hear a double-beep. [Here](https://freesound.org/data/previews/432/432088_8751484-lq.mp3) is a link to a recording of the sound.

I'm not positive that this is related to the 10.13.5 update, but it didn't happen before the update.

I would like to determine which process is responsible for this audio playback so that I can determine why it is happening.

Comment: Boot into Safe Mode, put the Mac to sleep and then wake it?  Are the sounds still present?  Also, test with a new user account.  This will help determine if it's system wide and/or user related.

Comment: Hi @Allan. Thanks for responding. I'm aware of the process of elimination route, but is there a more direct route? Maybe a way to see which process uses audio output at a specific time?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was calendar notifications. I noted the change when I upgraded to Mojave, that I got a notification sound whenever I opened the lid.  I had the calendar notification set to NONE - so there was no visual alert, but I had left "Play Sound" checked. It appears that if you have any notifications for the day, calendar alerts you on opening the lid. I toggled on the visual alert to confirm and, yep -- it was calendar alerts. Turned off sound and all was well.

System Preferences > Notifications:

[image]

Comment: This is interesting. I do not use the native Calendar app. Is the sound you heard the same sound as the one linked in my question? (By the way, I am not hearing this sound any longer.)

Comment: No, it wasn't -- but I customized my alerts so I wouldn't expect it to be. Even though you don't use the native calendar app, the pattern may hold for some other notification: visual alert is off, sound is activated, and it's a status that the mac checks against notifcation automatically on lid open.